# Python Social auth redirecting to the same URL

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, python-social-auth

After I choose some view with the decorator login_required() the user is redirected to: http://example.com/login/?**next=/anuncio/adicionar/**, right?

But, after I use "Login with facebook", the user are redirected to [http://example.com/login/#*=*](http://example.com/login/#_=_) instead of http://example.com/anuncio/adicionar/

It happens only if I use the python-social-auth, and not happens if I use the auth native login.

My registration/login.html - Python Social Auth link

```
<a class="btn btn-social btn-fw btn-lg btn-facebook" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Fazer login com Facebook</a>
```

and my Auth native login

```
<form action="{% url "auth:login" %}" role="form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add login redirect url to your settins.py file

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/anuncio/adicionar/'
```

so when user is authenticated it will tedirect the above url

Comment: It cannot be a non-dinamic URL. I need to redirect the user to a dynamic url. Sometimes will be "/anuncio/adicionar", sometimes "/empresa/adicionar/"

Comment: yes you can do that. create one view for this url and in that view use httpresponseredirect. so you can redirect anywhere you want. You can put dynamic url in httpresponseredirect.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding these in your `config.py` (if imported to `settings.py`, if not - add in `settings.py`):

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/anuncio/adicionar/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/login'
```

These definitions determine the redirection url after authentication using facebook.

Comment: I got it. But if I need to send to a dynamic url? Sometimes will be will be "/anuncio/adicionar", sometimes "/empresa/adicionar/", ...

Comment: You can pass the url for another redirection/replace on server side, using the session. Facebook is said to pass the session identifier.

Comment: Maybe my question is why the Python Social Auth are not following the "next=" param.

Comment: When did facebook say they follow the `next` parameter? You may be able to use the oauth `callback_uri` parameter, but I never heard of `next`. That will probably make the python-social-auth redundant if you start handling everything on your own.