# How to specify explicit host name in Django settings?

Tags: django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm working on a Django project that runs via several Docker containers and the Django site itself is a middleware that an Nginx container forwards requests to. And for testing the port 80 of the Nginx container is mapped to 8080. Thus I go to http://localhost:8080/ and see the Django website.

I'm having the issue that a redirect URL (constructed by `social-auth-app-django` package for Google Login) uses `http://localhost` as a base rather than `http://localhost:8080`.

The setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` isn't what I'm looking for because it occurs *after* authentication is successful.

I tried `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` which was [mentioned somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688835/python-social-auth-redirecting-to-the-same-url) but that was for an old version and no longer appears to do anything.

Since Django uses [build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) for all absolute URLs, there must be a way to override the base URL and/or host?

Comment: Is the redirection happening at the Nginx level or the django level?

Comment: @MattSeymour - At the Django level as part of the `social-auth-app-django` package. I'm going to dig into the source code when I have a moment. I'm sure this is a common issue that I'm asking about incorrectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436271/django-social-auth-redirect-to-url-with-port-number?

Comment: @solarissmoke - Similar issue but with the reverse problem: I want to _add_ the port (8080) not strip it out. However, there may be something I can do in Nginx to pass along the port number received. Thanks for the link; I'll try some of this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR = Nginx has no concept of Docker-mapped ports and needs to have them hard-coded.

Similar Issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf

Django requires that the HTTP request headers contain the information it needs for the host (code snippet below). In this case it needs to be passed in from Nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:7000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Note the unfortunate hard-coding of the port: `$host:8080`. The "outer" problem is that the port of the Nginx container is mapped using Docker to 8080 (`-p 80:8080`) and thus it has *no idea* that it's actually running on port 8080; Nginx detects itself as running on port 80.

There *is* a Django setting for `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` but specifying it like so:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/complete/google-oauth2/'
```

Causes this to happen when trying to authenticate through Google:

> **AuthMissingParameter at /complete/google-oauth2/**
>
> Missing needed parameter state
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://localhost:8080/complete/google-oauth2/
>
> Django Version:   2.1.5
>
> Exception Type:   AuthMissingParameter
>
> Exception Value:
>
> Missing needed parameter state
>
> Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py in validate_state, line 88
>
> Python Executable:    /usr/local/bin/python
>
> Python Version:   3.6.10

Thus the only solution I have at this point is to bake the port into the Nginx configuration when building the Docker image.

#### Django version 2.1.5 code for getting host:

```
def _get_raw_host(self):
    """
    Return the HTTP host using the environment or request headers. Skip
    allowed hosts protection, so may return an insecure host.
    """
    # We try three options, in order of decreasing preference.
    if settings.USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST and (
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' in self.META):
        host = self.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
    elif 'HTTP_HOST' in self.META:
        host = self.META['HTTP_HOST']
    else:
        # Reconstruct the host using the algorithm from PEP 333.
        host = self.META['SERVER_NAME']
        server_port = self.get_port()
        if server_port != ('443' if self.is_secure() else '80'):
            host = '%s:%s' % (host, server_port)
    return host
```

Comment: Running Nginx within ELB for HTTPS has a similar issue. I found a solution to that here: https://tecadmin.net/force-redirect-https-behind-aws-elb/